# Netlogo: identify all patches beyond a linear feature

Tags: netlogo

**Background:** I'm modeling territory selection in NetLogo. Turtles occupy a landscape divided by roads. Each turtle selects its territory center and then builds a territory. The turtle selects patches for its territory by ownership value, which is based on food versus travel costs. Travel costs include distance, and should also include whether reaching the patch requires crossing a road.

**Goal:** I would like each turtle to identify all patches that would require crossing a road in order to reach the patch from the territory center. The turtle should then assign higher costs to those patches. Each turtle will occupy a different part of the landscape, so these costs will be specific to each turtle. **How might this be done?**

**Example:** here is a landscape with two turtles:
[image]

**Example code:** I've added a few lines for an idea of how to possibly approach a way to hold road-costs for each turtle, but don't know how these would be calculated or if there is a better way to hold this information while building territories:

```
patches-own
[ owner  ;; turtle who claims patch for territory
  benefit  ;; i.e., food 
  primary-feature  ;; either "road" or null

  ;; Need a way to calculate and remember road-related patch costs for each turtle,
  ;; which are based on whether the turtle must cross a road to reach the patch. 
  ;; Perhaps this could be a patch variable tied to each turtle as follows:
  road-costs-to-turtle-1 
  road-costs-to-turtle-2 
  ;; etc...? If so, these would be calculated after turtle chooses a territory center.
]

turtles-own
[ start-patch  ;; my territory center
  destination  ;; my next patch to claim
  territory  ;; patches I own
]

to go
     pick-center
     pick-patch
end    

to pick-center
     setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     set start-patch (patch-here)
     ;; Turtle selects a patch for its territory center. Turtle will next need
     ;; to calculate costs for patches based on whether a patch requires crossing 
     ;; a road to reach it. I'm at a loss for how to identify all patches beyond 
     ;; roads from the turtle's perspective, however.
end

to pick-patch
    if patch-here = start-patch [ set destination highest-value ]
    ;; Turtle travels to and adds patches to its territory once reaches destination.
end

to-report highest-value            
     let available-destinations (patch-set [neighbors4] of territory) with [owner = nobody]   
     report max-one-of available-destinations ([benefit-to-me / cost-to-me]) 
end

to-report benefit-to-me
     report benefit ;; i.e., food value of patch
end

to-report cost-to-me
     let road-cost ;;<--??? 
     ;; Not sure how to identify if patches are past a road and thus costlier.
     ;; If this is a patches-own variable, then the coding may be something like:
     if who = 1 [let road-cost road-cost-to-turtle-1] ;; etc. 

     report distance [start-patch] of myself + road-cost
end
```

Comment: Have you take a look to [GIS extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html) ? If you work with polygons, you can defend what is inside and outside.

Answer (score 2):

While the suggestion to use the GIS is a good one, I thought you might also want a way to do it without that. One easy, but computationally intensive way to do it, is to "grow" the turtle's territory until it can't go any further:

```
to-report claim-territory [ current-territory ]
  let territory-size count current-territory
  ; Combine all non-road neighbors of the current territory with the current territory
  set current-territory (patch-set
    current-territory
    ([ neighbors4 with [ primary-feature != "road" ] ] of current-territory)
  )
  ifelse count current-territory > territory-size [
    report claim-territory current-territory
  ] [
    report current-territory
  ]
end
```

This will report all patches connected to those in `current-territory` that do not cross a road. You then call it like so, after calling `pick-center`:

```
set territory claim-territory (patch-set start-patch)
```

Then, to get a cost of a patch:

```
to-report cost [ target-patch ]
  ifelse member? target-patch territory [
    ; Compute and report cost of in territory patch
  ] [
    ; Compute and report cost of out of territory patch
  ]
end
```

If this is too computationally intensive, let me know, and I can discuss optimization.